# ACF - get all fields of a page or post (including sub fields)

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Im using ACF pro and for a search loop I need to get all fields of a page or post including subfields (repeaterfield) into an array for processing, so i can extract data like "name" and "value" from the array-objects.

I was trying "get_field_objects(mypageid);" which seems neat, but it only gets the first level fields. I need to get the subfields too.

I was looking around and right now it seems there isnt anything out of the box for it with ACF, but what would be the best way to get this data? Especially since every subfield could have subfields themself. I fail to wrap my head around a loop function for that. Has anyone ever written a loop for exactly that?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
ANB_Seth

Comment: get_fields() returns all fields and subfields as an array, then you should be able to loop through that

Comment: try writing this in your code, so that you can see it properly - <?php highlight_string("<?php\n\$fields =\n" . var_export(get_fields(), true) . ";\n?>"); ?>

Comment: thank you but ... I just dont get it. get_fields may give me the first level fields, but not the sublevel fields, and the sublevel fields of those etc. ... I mean, yeah, it might give me those values wrapped in a multilevel array, but how do I cycle through that without the "key" for the subgroup, since get_fields only seems to give me "name" and "value" and how do I do that over and over ... I'm sorry it may be awfully simple but I just fail to construct a simple function to collect all the fields within a page/post. Its probably an undestanding problem on my end :-S

Comment: personally - when i use get_fields(), I get sublevel fields of the repeaters as well.

Comment: else : this guy basically had the same problem, where he wants to check if the sub fields has a repeater : https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/get-all-fields-sub-fields-of-a-post-repeater/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I have worked myself to this functons which seem to do the trick:

```
function abGetAllFields($pro_num){
    $tmpArr = get_field_objects($pro_num);
    $fillArray = array();
    foreach( $tmpArr as $tmpFieldObject ) {
        $fillArray = abGetAllFieldsCycle($fillArray, $tmpFieldObject["name"], $tmpFieldObject["value"]);
    }
    return $fillArray;
}

function abGetAllFieldsCycle($fillArray, $name, $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        foreach( $value as $key => $value ) {
            $fillArray = abGetAllFieldsCycle($fillArray, $key, $value);
        }
    } else {
        array_push($fillArray, [$name, $value]);
    }
    return $fillArray;
}

$myFieldArray = abGetAllFields($pageId);
```

There might be a better or easier way to do it, but heck, it did what I needed so I'll stop right there and thought I'd share my result :-)

Answer (score 0):

**How to Get ACF Repeater Field?**

add below code in your page or post

Example :

main ACF filed name :homepage_slider

Sub Field name : slider_title, slider_description

```
<?php 
    if( have_rows('homepage_slider') ):
        // loop through the rows of data
        while ( have_rows('homepage_slider') ) : the_row(); 
?>
        <h3><?php the_sub_field('slider_title'); ?></h3>
        <p><?php the_sub_field('slider_description'); ?></p>
<?php
        endwhile;       
    else :      
        // no rows found        
    endif;
?>
```

Comment: thanks for the post ... I tried around with something like that. But the problem is: if I do it this way, I'd have to know the field-names (in your example "slider_title" and "slider_description"). But I dont know them. In fact, I need to find them, together with all the other data of each field, like value, type etc.,, be it a normal or a subfield. I need a loop that gets me every field and subfield of a page/post into an array as objects ("id", "type", "name", "value" etc.)